# how to count the operations of mergesort and quicksort in Java?

Tags: java

I am writing a program that counts the operations of mergesort and quicksort.
I don't know where I should put the count++; (to count the operations) in.
Can someone help me with this?

Here are the codes for merge sort and quick sort.

MERGE SORT:

```
public void mergeSort(int [] data, int first, int n){

    int n1;
    int n2;

    if (n>1) {
        n1 = n/2;
        n2 = n-n1;           
        mergeSort(data,first,n1);
        mergeSort(data,first+n1,n2);
        merge(data,first,n1,n2);
    }

}//ends mergeSort method.

public void merge(int [] data, int first, int n1, int n2){
    int [] temp = new int[n1+n2];
    int copied = 0, copied1 = 0, copied2 = 0, i;

    while((copied1<n1) && (copied2<n2)){

        if(data[first+copied1] < data[first + n1 + copied2])
        temp[copied++] = data[first + (copied1++)];
        else
        temp[copied++] = data[first + n1 + (copied2++)];
    }

    while (copied1<n1)
        temp[copied++] = data[first + (copied1++)];
    while(copied2<n2)
        temp[copied++] = data[first + n1 + (copied2++)];

    for (i=0;i<n1+n2;i++)
        data[first+i] = temp[i];
}//ends merge method.
```

And Here is the code for QUICK SORT:

```
public void quickSort(int data[], int left, int right){

    int index = partition(data, left, right);
    if (left < index - 1){              
        quickSort(data, left, index - 1);    
    }
    if (index < right){              
        quickSort(data, index, right);
    }
}//ends quickSort method.

int partition(int data[], int left, int right){

    int i = left, j = right;
    int tmp;
    int pivot = data[(left + right) / 2];

    while (i <= j)
    {
        while (data[i] < pivot)
        i++;
        while (data[j] > pivot)
        j--;
        if (i <= j)
        {

            tmp = data[i];
            data[i] = data[j];
            data[j] = tmp;
            i++;
            j--;
        }
    }
    return i;
}//ends partition method.
```

Answer (score 4):

You should put the `++` whereever you have an "operation". What you call an operation is up to you. I could be a comparison, a swap or every line. You have the decide what is appropriate for you.

Answer (score 1):

In **merge sort**, below method is exactly the one doing the stuff: -

```
merge(data,first,n1,n2);
```

So, put one **count++** there..

And in **quick sort**.. it's : -

```
partition(data, left, right)
```

So, add **count++** there..

Your other method calls: - `mergesort()` and `quicksort()` are just **recursive calls**.. They will finally lead to the above two `methods` only..

But ultimately it all depends upon what you mean my 'count the operations'.. What you take as an `operation` to be is crucial..

It might be a `method execution`, or `every statement` can be an operation.. Or your loop.. It can mean anything..

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you're doing "big O" analysis, your "count of operations" is the number of iterations of the innermost loop.

- For your QuickSort example, that's easy: put your counter after `while (i <= j)`
- For your MergeSort example, you'll need to put your counter in each of the `while` loops (I haven't looked closely at these loops, but they seem to be doing far more than is necessary).

This count does *not* tell you the actual number of operations that you're performing, just the "big O" number of operations. While MergeSort and QuickSort may have the same "big O" characteristics (and therefore should have similar counts), the amount of work done inside the innermost loop will differ.